# chrome javascript content extension cut copy paste confusion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

Hi I'm trying to capture the buffer in cut copy paste.
I can get the paste, but the copy and cut do not appear to work.

**Env:**
Windows 10 x64:
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'> 

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'> 

<body>

<hr/>Clipboard TEST<br/>
<textarea id='idCut'
        rows='8'
        cols='32'>
Cut something from here 
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Stuff",
  "version": "2.0",

  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging",
        "notifications",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "downloads",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "clipboardRead",
        "*://*/*"
    ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page do Stuff"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**content.js**

```
function onCut(e)
{
    console.log( 'onCut ENTER' );

    var buf = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    console.log( 'onCut  EXIT ' + buf );
}

function onCopy(e)
{
    console.log( 'onCopy ENTER' );

    var buf = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    console.log( 'onCopy  EXIT ' + buf );
}

function onPaste(e)
{
    console.log( 'onPaste ENTER' );

    var buf = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

    console.log( 'onPaste  EXIT ' + buf );
}

document.addEventListener('cut',onCut,true); 
document.addEventListener('copy',onCopy,true); 
document.addEventListener('paste',onPaste,true);
```

I then select "something" from the text area and do ctrl X, ctrl C, ctrl V
which results in:

```
content.js:8 onCut ENTER
content.js:12 onCut  EXIT 
content.js:17 onCopy ENTER
content.js:21 onCopy  EXIT 
content.js:26 onPaste ENTER
content.js:30 onPaste  EXIT something
```

So, Paste gives me the buffer, but the others do not.

My question is why aren't cut and copy showing me the buffer but paste is?

I've read that I need to use background.js and exec the op into a temp dom element like a div, and then native message it out, but if that is true, why is paste working?  It seems like the security / impl is not consistent.

Is there a reason this is the way it is?
Or am I missing something?

I just added the html and manifest... Sorry, it didn't seem like it was needed because paste was working.  I *believe* that makes it complete?

Thanks

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet you most likely will get a proper answer, as of now it is difficult to _see_ what goes wrong.

Comment: I have 3 functions for the 3 events.  Is more code needed?  Sorry, not sure what else to provide

Comment: Then you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The clipbord is not easily, cross browser, accessible. Here are some more info: https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/ ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything cross browser.  I am only trying to find an explanation / documentation for the results I'm seeing, or acknowledgement of a potential bug.  Thanks